# Bootstrap: numbers from ordered list disapear when using media object

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to create a website. I'm trying to create an ordered list that consists of media objects for each item. When I do this, the numbers disappear when viewing on a tablet. However the numbers are there when you view the list from a desktop-browser with the window adjusted to a tablet resolution. How can I get the numbers to NOT disappear when viewing on a tablet?

```
<ol>                        
    <li>
        <div class="media">
            <a class="pull-right" href="#">
                <div class="span4"><img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
                <!-- Nested media object -->
                <div class="media">
                    blablabla
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Post some example CSS. Also, check the styles within the media query. Perhaps there's an override on `<ol>` tags which sets `list-style` to none, or the padding is set to 0, causing the numbers to display out of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I'm aware of bootstrap's responsive CSS, it doesn't do anything to lists in tablet view so you may be using another css rule somewhere which is hiding `list-style` for tablet viewport.

Another guess would be that the `list-style` is set to outside and there's an `overflow` or something that makes your `list-style` invisible. Add this line to your CSS file (after loading frameworks and other things) and see if it fixes the problem for you.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    ol { list-style: decimal inside; }
}
```

Comment: thank you, bootstrap.css (line 5588) has overflow: hidden. removing this seemed to work! thanks.