# How to make an ordered List with Twitter Bootstrap Component?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple ordered list, super easy:

http://www.bootply.com/P8wglPiSVD

Looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ol class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, aliquid.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <p>Quos nostrum provident ex quisquam aliquid, hic odio repellendus atque.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <p>Facilis, id dolorum distinctio, harum accusantium atque explicabo quidem consectetur.</p>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But twitter bootstrap isn't showing any numbers, even though it is an ordered list.

I searched but didn't find any twitter bootstrap compontent that styles ordered list items and this makes me curious. Is there a lacking in a predefined style for Twitter Bootstrap for ordered lists or am I missing something?

Kind regards,

George

Comment: With bootstrap, you can just use `<ol>` and `<li>` tags to accomplish a numbered (ordered) list - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-lists

Comment: @MikeK The OP is using `<ol>` and `<li>`.

Comment: @Juhana I meant using strictly `<ol>` and `<li>` without any additional classes applied to the list/items

Comment: The OP is specifically asking for ordered lists styled like a `list-group`. Without any classes the list won't be styled.

Comment: ...but now I see more of what the user wants, so my suggestion is moot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bootstrap is applying `display: block` to the list items, which kills the numbering. Add this to your CSS:

```
.list-group-item {
    display: list-item;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/ZHQBWK9sHB

Comment: Looks weird, but none the less it is working that way. I believe this feature is still lacking in Twitter Bootstrap Styling.

Answer (score 31):

Combining @Steve Sanders and @beiping_troop answers, you can create clean ordered list-groups with the following CSS:

```
.list-group {
    list-style: decimal inside;
}

.list-group-item {
    display: list-item;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/BJadu6Ja6R

Comment: This did the trick for me.  Instead of decimal I used upper-alpha.

Answer (score 3):

For just a clean ordered list, I chose an inline style override since I was only calling out a numbered list in one place. It rendered just fine:

```
<ol style="list-style: decimal inside;">
<li>First item</li>
<li>Second item</li>
<li>Third item</li>
</ol>
```

My reference was originally here: [Bootstrap: numbers from ordered list disapear when using media object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653364/bootstrap-numbers-from-ordered-list-disapear-when-using-media-object/)

Answer (score 3):

I found a better solution is to add a new css class to the list group depending on the style of numbering you want for example "list-group-numbered" or "list-group-alpha" that way you can add the numbering to only the ordered lists you want to add it to and not to all numbered lists, especially if you have somewhere else on the website that has numbered lists that now looks wrong...

```
.list-group-numbered { list-style: decimal inside; }
.list-group-alpha { list-style: lower-alpha inside; }
.list-group-roman { list-style: lower-roman inside; }
.list-group-alpha >li, .list-group-numbered >li { display: list-item }
```

then you can put in the following in html..

```
<ol class="list-group list-group-numbered">
    <li class="list-group-item">an item
        <ol class="list-group list-group-alpha">
            <li class="list-group-item">a sub item
                <ol class="list-group list-group-roman">
                    <li class="list-group-item">a sub-sub item</li>
                </ol>                
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">another item</li>        
    <li class="list-group-item">a third item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

Manual CSS style may get overridden by the bootstrap CSS, to force the above style put *!important* after the value

```
.list-group {
    list-style: decimal inside !important
}

.list-group-item {
    display: list-item !important
}
```

Comment: You should try to avoid using `!important`. It would be better to load your own stylesheets after the Bootstrap CSS so that they override the Bootstrap styles.