# Bootstrap and numbered lists

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and this markup,

```
<div id="panelSteps" class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading hidden-print">Actions</div>
  <ol class="item-steps list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Some action</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Other action</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Is is possible to have the list display numbers? I have tried overriding the OL [element's style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653364/bootstrap-numbers-from-ordered-list-disapear-when-using-media-object) with `list-style:decimal inside;` and `overflow:visible;`, etc.I can't get to see the numbers beside the list items.

Thank you!

Comment: Should we assume that you require the panel and other Bootstrap classes you have on there now?

Comment: @j08691 yes, thus why I wrote "and this markup".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to play with the styling until it's satisfactory design-wise but this will bring the numbers back:

```
.item-steps {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.list-group-item {
  display: list-item;
}
```

Comment: simply putting `display: list-item;` on the LI elements work. I totally missed that one :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fix: https://jsfiddle.net/9ehyyrct/ In the JSFiddle, I use Bootstrap 3.3.6 but it applies to 3.3.5 too.

Unfortunately it's pretty hacky:

```
.list-group-item {
    display: list-item;
    margin-left:30px;
}

.list-group-item a {
  margin-left:-10px;
}
```

The items show up when you add `display: list-item;` but they're hidden outside of the viewport.

Bootstrap sort of kicks your `ol`'s numbers to the left, so adding a margin helps them show. The `margin-left` on the anchor is to counteract the ugly margin I used to fix the issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the display value to list-item as said by @Fausto NA and try removing the margin left property and asking the list style position to inside.

```
.list-group {
    list-style-position: inside;
}

.list-group-item {
    display: list-item;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/femiva/s6p3ny31/2/)
 I have used with Bootstrap 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I was using an un-ordered list and simply wanted the bullets to display in bootstrap.
I ended up just adding an HTML dot (`&#8226;`) inside the `li` tag, with some non-breaking white space (for indentation).

`<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8226;&nbsp;&nbsp;my item</li>`